# How to login with encrypted password in django

Tags: python, django

I am using django.contrib.auth for authentication in my project, its working fine, Now i have to work on a module where super members have to login in it's member's account, he should have all the access of their account,

so I have to login with member's email id and their encrypted password automatically saved by django Auth while registering members.

```
user_existence = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).first()
    if user_existence:
        email = user_existence.email
        password = user_existence.password
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('user_connected')
        return HttpResponse('user_auth_failed')
```

Is is possible to encrypt this password or login with encrypted password, or it would be great if its having another solution.

Comment: You want to login with password hash that is generated by django?

Comment: Yes want to login with hashed password generated with django auth

Comment: Encrypted password is like :-    pbkdf2_sha256$24000$GT0uQ4jodKLe$UmSEWl7hquttwYyx2qiOXSA3nVU8Rn1Q3BNSff4+ok0=

Comment: Login in with a hashed password is a __very__ bad idea. It will basically break the extra security added by hashed passwords. What you should do it so write a view or a middleware that allows authenticated "super users" to switch the user without password.

Comment: @KlausD. How can i do that, super user don't know the password of sub-user, but he can login with their email id as project needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply log in as a certain user using

```
user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
login(request, user)
```

No need to run `authenticate()`.

Comment: would it work same like django auth, because i have already implemented it for my complete project

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Returned error:- global name 'django' is not defined

Comment: As per documentation, we must have call authenticate function before login

Comment: You don't have to.

Comment: But its giving me error 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

Comment: Now error is:- 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: what if cannot do this since I want to log this user in another sever that shares the same db

Comment: @Kailegh create a new question explaining your situation

Comment: I did it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58396717/django-send-authenticated-user-to-another-django-server-with-the-same-db

Answer (score 1):

**Django 2.x**

You can create a custom authentication backend and override its authenticate method to authenticate using hashed password and username

```
# backends.py
from django.contrib.auth import backends, get_user_model


UserModel = get_user_model()


class HashedPasswordAuthBackend(backends.ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        else:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.password == password and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
        return super().authenticate(request, username, password, **kwargs)
```

Then include this authentication backend in your project *settings.py*

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'yourapp.backends.HashedPasswordAuthBackend',
]
```