# Django send authenticated user to another django server with the same db

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I know question sounds strange, I will explain it here.
I have two Django servers which share the same DB. One is a light front/back server and the order one takes the heavy computing part. They share the same database.
I am currently securing the web, and I have a couple of views in the light server requiring user login:

```py
@login_required() 
@permission_required('auth.can_upload', login_url='/accounts/login/')
```

This works nicely in the light server since the user is authenticated (request.user returns a valid user in the views).

The problem comes when I have to send the uploaded data to the other server since it is protected as I showed earlier, I do not know how to pass it the user that is already logged (user is valid since servers share the DB).

```py
# send an upload request using requests
s = requests.Session()

r1 = s.get(upload_process_url)
csrf_token = r1.cookies['csrftoken']
a = s.post(upload_process_url, files=request.FILES,
                   data={'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token},
                   headers=dict(Referer=upload_process_url))
```

I cannot ask every time the user and password or save them. The thing is I want to pass the user that is already logged in a request.
The user was logged using the default django `accounts/login` page and authentication.

Any clues and what could I try? I think this problem cannot be as difficult as it looks to me. I just want to send an authenticated request. If I remove the decorators everything works nicely with this code

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [REMOTE_USER authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/auth-remote-user/):

> This document describes how to make use of external authentication sources (where the Web server sets the REMOTE_USER environment variable) in your Django applications. This type of authentication solution is typically seen on intranet sites, with single sign-on solutions such as IIS and Integrated Windows Authentication or Apache and mod_authnz_ldap, CAS, Cosign, WebAuth, mod_auth_sspi, etc.

Basically your "light" server does the authentication as it already does. When you are doing a request to your "heavy" server, you should set a `Auth-User` header containing the username of your user. Django will then automatically authenticates the corresponding user.

By default, Django will read an environment variable set by an authentication server. But we can make it work with a HTTP header instead:

```py
# middlewares.py

from django.contrib.auth.middleware import RemoteUserMiddleware

class CustomHeaderMiddleware(RemoteUserMiddleware):
    header = 'HTTP_AUTH_USER'
```

```py
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    '...',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'my_project.middlewares.CustomHeaderMiddleware',
    '...',
]
```

Then, you can do something like this then in your request (assuming you have your Django `user` at hand):

```py
s = requests.Session()

r1 = s.get(upload_process_url)
a = s.post(
    upload_process_url,
    files=request.FILES,
    headers={
        'Auth-User': user.username,
    },
)
```

Since you're not doing a request from a browser, you can avoid the CSRF protection by marking the called "heavy" view with `@csrf_exempt` decorator (as you found yourself).

Be careful though that your "heavy" server should not be accessible directly on the internet and always behind a proxy/VPN accessible only by your "light" server.

Comment: I think that might be what I need. But I am not sure of how to send the REMOTE_USER with requests, could you enlighten me? thanks a lot

Comment: @Kailegh Edited my answer with an example. Don't forget before to configure your Django as per the documentation I linked.

Comment: if I remove the CSRF token I get an error, anyway this is not working for me. I have set eveything that the django documentation says, but when I pass the remote_user like that it does not work.  
However if a set REMOTE_USER it with a enviroment variable it works, problem is it is note getting passed in the headers I think, or detected

Comment: ok, I have more or less made it work, I will post a detailed answer later, my problem now is that by using the REMOTE_USER I get a new CSRF token each time so I the method I posted is not working, I get this:
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):

Comment: I went a bit too quick in my explanation about HTTP headers, I've updated my answer. About CSRF, you're right, you should mark your views with `@csrf_exempt`.

Comment: I was writing my own answer but you have already done it, although the problem with the csrf is not the browser, I can the csrf from the cookies doing a previuos get request, the problem is that when I do the post I get logged again and the old csrf is not valid anymore (I think) but your answer is what I did and works, so thanks a lot!